# How to get the value before ( - 001) from SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a SQL query to get value before -001

For example, from the input --> ex 1: 10008601-001
ex 2: 25525601-021

I need the output --> 10008601 or 25525601

i need only the numbers before -001 or -021

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What if you have a hyphen followed by something else?

Comment: Is the structure always exactly the same? One or more digits, a dash (hyphen), and one or more digits? (What if, for example, the input is all digits, without a hyphen? Is that ever possible, and if it is, what is the desired output?) And is the task to always return the first group of digits, before hyphen? If so, then you already have two answers, but both rely heavily on this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I think `regexp_substr()` is a simple way to do this:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^-]+')
```

Note:  This returns everything before the `-`, which seems to be what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination (line #6) is one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '10008601-001' from dual union all
  3     select '25525601-021' from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-') -1) result
  7  from test;

COL          RESULT
------------ ------------
10008601-001 10008601
25525601-021 25525601

SQL>
```